# Как сделать чтобы функция не срабатывала во второй раз, если я делаю то же самое

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на одну и ту же form дважды или больше, функция не работала? Но при нажатии на другие form (Не та что ранее) функция работала вновь, и после если нажать обратно на ту изначальную, функция должна понять что её нажимают впервые

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on('click', function (e) {
        var files = [];
        var cnt = 0;
        $(this).siblings().addBack().each(function () {
            files[cnt] = $(this).text();
            cnt++;

        });
        var text = files[0].substr(0, files[0].indexOf("Delete"));
        var textarea = text.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
        $('#myTextarea').val(textarea.toString());
        $('#myTextarea').innerHTML = textarea.toString();
        console.log(cnt)
        for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            console.log(files[i])
        }
        console.log(textarea);
        // console.log("Textarea value is " + $('#myTextarea').val());
        console.log("Textarea value is " + textarea);
    });
});


<td id="<%=cnt%>" data-toggle="modal"
data-target="#uiModal">
<% cnt++;%>
<div tabindex="0" class="multi">
    <form action="../java/Save.jsp"
          method="post">
        <textarea name="text" rows="4" cols="25"
                  class="border border-info"
                  style="font-size: 4px; margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 2px; border: 0.5px solid #001f3f !important;"><%=task[i * 15 + k]%></textarea>
        <br>
        <a style="font-size: 2px; width: 15px; padding-left: 0.5px; padding-right: 0.5px;"
           class="btn"
           href=<%= "\"../java/DeleteTask.jsp?primaryid=" + PrimaryID + "&username=" + username + "&id=" + 11 + "\"" %>>Delete</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="primaryid"
               value="<%=PrimaryID%>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="username"
               value="<%=username%>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="id"
               value="<%=i * 15 + k%>"/>
        <input class="btn" type="submit"
               value="Save"
               style="width: 15px; font-size: 2px; padding-left: 0.5px; padding-right: 0.5px;">
    </form>
    <form action="../java/MoveTask.jsp"
          method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="text"
               value="<%=task[i * 15 + k]%>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="primaryid"
               value="<%=PrimaryID%>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="username"
               value="<%=username%>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="id"
               value="<%=i * 15 + k%>"/>
        <select class="ui-select" size="3"
                style="margin-left: 2px; font-size: 2px; width: 24.5px;"
                name="first" required>
            <option value="1">В очереди</option>
            <option value="2">В работе</option>
            <option value="3">На тесте</option>
            <option value="4">Выполнено</option>
            <option value="5">На сопровождении
            </option>
        </select>
        <select class="ui-select" size="3"
                style="font-size: 2px; width: 10px;"
                name="second" required>
            <%
                for (int j = 1; j <= 15; j++) {
            %>
            <option><%=j%>
            </option>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </select>
        <input class="btn" type="submit"
               value="Move"
               style="width: 15px; font-size: 2px; padding-left: 0.5px; padding-right: 0.5px;">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Храните в отдельном объекте ключ-значение - форма-сколькоРазНажали. И смотрите каждый раз в него. А при клике манипулируйте этим объектом

Comment: можно попробовать использовать селектор `:focus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я понял должно было получиться чтото такое :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let previousClickedId;
  $('form').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!previousClickedId || previousClickedId != this.id) {
      console.log(`new click, id = ${this.id} (do something)`);
      previousClickedId = this.id;
    } else {
      console.log(`same click, id = ${this.id} (do nothing)`);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="1">1</form>
<form id="2">2</form>
<form id="3">3</form>
```

Comment: А можно обойтись без ID? Просто у меня в одной дивке несколько form, но если эту дивку я нажал, оно не должно повторно вызывать функцию

Comment: Можно ли как-нибудь привязать функцию к div? Например если id у див от 0 до 74 включительно, то функция запустилась, и там уже настроить все это?

Comment: Или есть ли что-то, на что можно привязать функцию, но не является div?

Comment: добавте тогда хоть примерную разметку, так как в вопросе у вас все на формах описано, а в коментариях сейчас пишете что всетаки див, в котором много форм.
ПС: чем точнее вопрос тем проще на него ответить )

Comment: добавил код, у меня 5 table-ов по 15 таких td, прохожусь фориком i = 0; i < 5; i++  => j = 0; j < 15; j++; и отрисовываю одинаково все td, могу дать tdшкам уникальный id от 0 до 74

Comment: тоесть у вас уже не дивы а тд-шки ?) ну и если можете дать уникальные ид то давайте и используйте их

Comment: Ваше решение мне помогло, но теперь дальше мне нужно продумать логику, просто оно ссылается не туда куда надо) Спасибо большое

Comment: Если можете помочь как логику расставить, был бы рад

Comment: думаю что ето уже тема нового вопроса )